# Stackview axis change is delayed

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, autolayout, uistackview

I have a tableview cell with a UIStackView. In my cellForRow method I change the axis of the stackview, depending on certain factors, from horizontal to vertical.

For some reason, this change is delayed slightly when I push a viewcontroller containing the table cell onto my navigationcontroller. It's as if the axis change is done after the push animation is completed. Thus, when the viewcontroller and the cell first appear on screen, the axis is horizontal and it changes to vertical once the animation is completed.

If the viewcontroller containing the table cell is the rootviewcontroller, the change happens instantly, so the problem seems to be a combination of pushing a viewcontroller and changing the stackview axis at the same time.

I have tried using self.layoutIfNeeded() after changing the access, to force layout changes immediately, but this doesn't seem to change anything.

Has anyone seen this behavior before, and is there a solution?

Comment: Where are you adding the code to change the stack view axis?

Comment: It resides in the table cell class and is executed in the cellForRow method in the viewcontroller.

Comment: Table View will be reloaded only after the view controller is completely loaded in the memory and it happens only after the push animation is completed.

Comment: Try moving the axis change code to main queue. It might resolve the problem. I am not sure,

Comment: The axis change is already made on the main queue. I managed to solve this however. Please see my answer below, if you're interested :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, I managed to solve this by setting the axis in the cell's traitCollectionDidChange method as well. This method is always called when the cell is created and seems to update the layout before the push animation begins.